# Do I need hive-metastore when I use unity catalog

Tags: hive, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

We have a databricks in azure portal and from the beginning we set up unity catalog. UC works fine we have schemas and tables there. By default there is also hive_metastore which is not working - we did not set up Hive metastore.

In the cluster log there is always error *Metastore Down*:

[image]

When I run query I can see that query stuck on this task for about 5 minutes.

> performing Hive catalog operation databaseExists task.

[image]

Questions:

- do I need to set up Hive Metastore even if I will never use it because I use Unity Catalog?
- Can I somehow avoid databaseExists operation for queries?

Thanks.

Comment: Adding spark configuration options for external metastore into cluster advanced options helped reduce catalog operation to few seconds. But Im still confused do I need hive metastore?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/archive/external-metastores/external-hive-metastore#download-the-metastore-jars-and-point-to-them